# MVC + WebApi architecture translations in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

For the application I'm currently developing using the .net MVC stack, and WebApi I need to put translations in the database.

My entities look something like this:

```
public class Article {
  public int Id { get; set; }

  TitleTranslatableId { get; set; }

  [NotMapped]
  TitleValue { get; set; }

}
```

So `TitleTranslatableId` is a reference to a table in my database.

**The question I'm currently having is:**

Where should I get the translation? I've considering the following options:

- In my repository layer, so when I use _repo.ReadArticle(1) it also queries the translations table
- Business layer
- In my controller using a translations controller so: `article.titleValue = translationsAPI(article.TitleTranslatableId)`
- As a derived attribute in my entity:
  `TitleValue { get { return translationsAPI(this.TitleTranslatableId); } }`

I would prefer to use the third option but I'm not quite sure what is the best solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend doing this in your "BUSINESS LAYER".

You controller should instruct your service/business layer to do the translation for you. You could create a `TranslationHelper` class which could be used by your service.

Though still am not sure what your question is: You want to get the translation of the word using web api or save after translating a word sent to your web api ?